# What parameters affect between autoreset.set() and autoreset exit from wait handle

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5, delay, autoresetevent

Most of the time it immediately exit from waitone handle practically on same tickcount but some times it takes 100 to 200 tickcount. What parameters affect between AutoReset.set() method and exit from waitHandle ?

Comment: Which language? Mind sharing code?

Comment: vb.net is language, Windows 32 platform and Framework 3.5